# Get code from protected PIC

Tags: hardware, pic, security, dumping

I have a [PIC18F4550](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39632c.pdf) from an old device and I need to see the code. I tried reading it using my ICD3 programmer, but the chip seems to have its code protected. How can I get the code anyway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the paper [Heart of Darkness - exploring the uncharted backwaters of HID iCLASS TM security](http://www.openpcd.org/images/HID-iCLASS-security.pdf)
 is a technique described (section III.C) that might work,but it does require a working device which might not be at hand in your situation.

In short they use a TTL-232 cable in synchronous bit bang mode to emulate the PIC programmer. They then override the boot block by a special dumper firmware. Why it seems to work:

> Microchip PIC microcontrollers internal memory is an EEPROM which means that data are stored and erase by pages (which hold a predefined amount of data).
>   The "key" point is that , whenever memory is copy protected, individual blocks can be erased resetting the copy protection bits only for these blocks.

Comment: @Gilles my bad, I'm new to the Stack Exchange network and its ethics (=bad excuse). In my defense, my laziness to read the FAQ lost from my desire to answer the question quickly. I've edited to original response to be more constructive.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly the right way to describe an external resource.